# Database design to satisfy 3NF

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to design a db but I'm having some difficulties.
I have

```
Students
id, name, group, year of study, specialization, list of scolarships
```

and

```
Scolarships
id, name, description, duration, list of applicants
```

From what I have read so far I know that there can't be a list stored in a cell. So my question is: *How could I represent those two list from each table I have so far?*

I was thinking of creating another table, but I don't know how to design it. Please help me with some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to create a third table (which I call `Bridge`) which contains the relationships between students and their scholarships.  This table will contain two *foreign* keys pointing to the `Students` and `Scholarships` tables.  When you want to get a list of students and their scholarships, you will use this table to connect the two normalized tables in your original problem.

```
Students (id, name, group, year of study, specialization)           id is a primary key
Scholarships (id, name, description, duration)                      id is a primary key
Bridge (student_id, scholarship_id)                                 both are foreign keys
```

Then when you want to get a list of students with their scholarships you do a `JOIN` query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Students st
    INNER JOIN Bridge b ON st.id = b.student_id
    INNER JOIN Scholarships sc ON b.scholarship_id = sc.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
Students(id,name,group,year of study, spec)
    Scolarships(id,name,description,duration)
    Applicants(scolarshipID,studentID)
```